# How do I push or pull to multiple git remote server

Tags: git, github, jenkins, gitlab, bitbucket

I have an existing repository in Github then I have decided to host this repository also bitbucket and gitlab.

Then I add a remote repository of GitLab and bitbucket to the git config and successfully push to multiple servers.
Push is working when changing on local machine/pc and GitHub also working when changing on GitHub online server and pull commit and push again to all remote servers.

The problem is when I have changed any code from bitbucket or GitLab and then try to pull to a local machine/pc it not pulling. So, I have changed something in my local machine/pc then after commit tries to push but the push is working only GitHub and Gitlab+Bitbucket push not working (not updating remote repositories).

```
asifulmamun@asifulmamun:~/script/Youtube-Projects$ git push
Everything up-to-date
To bitbucket.org:asifulmamun/youtube-projects.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:asifulmamun/youtube-projects.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
To gitlab.com:asifulmamun/youtube-projects.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:asifulmamun/youtube-projects.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Gitlab and Bitbucket remote server telling me to pull the repository then try to for the push. But, the pull not working. **Showing me all up to date because this pull is working only for GitHub, not for Bitbucket and Gitlab.**

```
asifulmamun@asifulmamun:~/script/Youtube-Projects$ git pull
Already up to date.
```

**However, if the pull not working from Bitbucket or Gitlab server how I will push them again after changing something from local repositories.**

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set two different `remotes` (tracked repositories) to your project:

```
git remote add bitbucket <the_path_for_bitbucket_project>
git remote add gitlab <the_path_for_gitlab_project>
```

Then, whenever you want to pull from `bitbucket` for instance, you could run:

```
git pull bitbucket <branch_name>
```

Then if you want to push something to `gitlab` for instance, you could run:

```
git push gitlab <branch_name>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working `git push gitlab master` or `git push -u gitlab master`